# JAX-WS WebMethods authorization code duplicates

Tags: java, web-services, certificate, jax-ws, code-duplication

I have a number of `WebMethods` using JAX-WS and every method should be authenticated using client certificate. Therefore I need to read DN from client certificate and other information which should be used in authorisation process.

The sample method looks like this:

```
    @WebMethod
    public String sampleMethod(
            @XmlElement(required = true)
                @WebParam(name="attribute") String one,
            @XmlElement(required = true)
                @WebParam(name="attribute2") String two) throws Exception {
        String message = null;
        String clientDN = getClientDN();

        if (isAuthorized(clientDN)) {
            // Do something
        }

        return message;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String sampleMethod2(
            @XmlElement(required = true)
                @WebParam(name="attribute") String one,
            @XmlElement(required = true)
                @WebParam(name="attribute2") String two) throws Exception {
        String message = null;
        String clientDN = getClientDN();

        if (isAuthorized(clientDN)) {
            // Do something
        }

        return message;
    }

    private String getClientDN() {
        HttpsExchange exchange = (HttpsExchange) context.getMessageContext().get(HTTPS_EXCHANGE);
        SSLSession sslsession = exchange.getSSLSession();
        try {
            String name = sslsession.getPeerPrincipal().getName();
            log.debug("client DN: " + name);
            return name;
        } catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So in this case I need to get client certificate DN in every `WebMethod` defined and this duplicates the code.

I was looking into handler classes but I don't see a way how to do it with it because the handler is basically independent from service class.

Is there a way how to do authorisation globally for the whole web service? Also I would need to pass client DN into service after successful authorisation to work with it.

Comment: is there any specific reason to do not use standard SSL Truststore mechanism for certificates and WSSE for user authentication?

Comment: Yes. I am using standard mutual authentication based on client and server certificates, when accessing web services, but I need to do a further application level authorization based on client certificate. Therefore I need a little bit more than standard SSL Truststore mechanism.

Comment: Include a jax-ws interceptor before your webmethod is invoked, extract the ssl certificate, and abort the connection if validation fails. If validation is correct you can add user data to the message or use a ThreadLocal

Comment: OK. Got it. but are you aware of two(or one) line of duplicate code:

`if (isAuthorized(getClientDN()))` ? Or is it about getClientDN() method duplicated accross multiple services?

Comment: interceptor is definitely good for common case, but to remove one if statement... I'm not sure about that. IMHO "as is" code is more understandable from simple first glance.

Comment: If sou are talking about interceptor as handlers, is it possible to check what web method is client trying to call and based on that check authorisation? For example, if there are methods with different types of authorisation or without authorisation at all.

Comment: handlers and interceptors are the same. For example `public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {` I am not sure if you can extract the bussiness method from `context`. Try `context.get(MessageContext.WSDL_OPERATION)`